# What is the difference between Analog Input and Internal Microphone?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, microphone

I am running Ubuntu 14.04, and my sound works just fine. However, when I open the `Sound` dialog, I notice that under `Input` there are two available options

[image: Two options for sound input]

As far as I can tell, my laptop has an integrated microphone and a small port where I can connect an external microphone, but this does not explain the two entries since I think they are both receiving input from the built-in microphone.

So, what is the difference?

Addition: I should note that both of the actually work just fine. I did some more investigation using `pavucontrol` which actually gives three options

[image]

I still don't quite understand what is going on, and why there are additional options. Perhaps a `pulse` expert can jump in?

Answer (score 0):

On the computers I have tried, Pulseaudio always use internal mic as audio input until a physical jack is connected to the external input jack plug: then it autoswitch to this external input, muting the internal mic.
In other words, there are 2 settings but only one is active depending on the external input jack connection.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a microphone plugged in, or have a laptop that has a built in microphone (which you do) it's most likely going to be the analog one.  The internal one is likely a sound card or something, and doesn't actually pick up sound.  I have 5 different sound outputs, but only 1 that will work currently.  However, I only have one input device.  It tends to vary on each PC as to what hardware they will have equipped.  I wouldn't worry about it, as I'm sure it's not causing any issues.